# Can I check if there are any changes in any of my projects that have not been committed to their Git repo

Tags: git

I have 100s of projects, each with its own Git repository. I want to make sure that there are no changes that have not been committed. I could go to each project individually and check but I want to be able to do all of them in one go. Or to put it another way, I want to find all the git repositories on my hard drive and check to see if there are any unstaged changes for each one.

Comment: loot at this [documentation](https://www.electricmonk.nl/log/2016/12/06/multi-repo-git-status-checking-script/)

Comment: Any standard Unix shell (/bin/sh, /bin/bash, etc) is easily programmed to do this sort of thing: `for path in <list of paths>; do cd $HOME/projects/path; git status; done` for instance. Turning this into a more personally-useful script is an easy but good exercise for the user. The resulting small script will tend to be custom to each particular user (because project paths tend to be personalized).

Comment: `locate -b \*.git`